# Forest: Logical & conditional in where statement

Tags: forest

How can I include a logical `&` in the `where` conditional so that the conditional doesn't match Parents 4-8 with only one child so that they grow normally north-south? i.e. changing the conditional to something like: `where n children=0 & parent.n children>1`

### MWE

[image: Family tree]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw=black,align=center,parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,
    edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
        (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-0.125in) -|
        (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    where n children=0{
        child anchor=west,
        for parent={
            parent anchor=south,
            grow'=east,calign=child edge
        }
    }{}
}
[Root
    [Parent 1
        [,phantom]
        [Child 1]
        [Child 2]
        [Child 3]
    ]
    [Parent 2
        [Child 1
            [,phantom]
            [Child 1]
            [Child 2]
        ]
    ]
    [Parent 3
        [,phantom]
        [Child 1]
        [Child 2]
        [Child 3]
    ]
    [Parent 4
        [Only Child 1]
    ]
    [Parent 5
        [Only Child 1]
    ]
    [Parent 6
        [Only Child 1]
    ]
    [Parent 7
        [Only Child 1]
    ]
    [Parent 8
        [Only Child 1]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a solution to your problem:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={
    draw=black,align=center,parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,
    edge path={
        \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
        (!u.parent anchor) -- +(0,-0.125in) -|
        (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    },
    if={level>0}{% skip root (reason: root has no parent)
        if={n_children==0 && n_children("!parent")>1}{% changed to if and added additional condition
            child anchor=west,
            for parent={
                parent anchor=south,
                grow'=east,calign=child edge
            }
        }{}
    }{}
}
[Root
    [Parent 1
        [,phantom]
        [Child 1]
        [Child 2]
        [Child 3]
    ]
    [Parent 2
        [Child 1
            [,phantom]
            [Child 1]
            [Child 2]
        ]
    ]
    [Parent 3
        [,phantom]
        [Child 1]
        [Child 2]
        [Child 3]
    ]
    [Parent 4
        [Only Child 1]
    ]
    [Parent 5
        [Only Child 1]
    ]
    [Parent 6
        [Only Child 1]
    ]
    [Parent 7
        [Only Child 1]
    ]
    [Parent 8
        [Only Child 1]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]